# Tag dispatching by type invokes expected primary-expression error

Tags: templates, c++11

I am working on Tag dispatching implementation in my SW and am facing weird behavior of my code. Let the code tells more:

I have tag system as follows:

```
struct GEAR_EXPORT GearParams
{
    struct ParameterType
    {
        using IDType = int;
    };

    struct GEAR_EXPORT NUM_OF_TEETH : public ParameterType
    {
        /* NUM_OF_TEETH parameter's unit type definition */
        using UnitType = si::dimensionless;
        /* NUM_OF_TEETH parameter's data type definition */
        using DataType = short;
        /* NUM_OF_TEETH parameter's DesignRules DB ID */
        using ID = std::integral_constant<ParameterType::IDType, 1>;
    };

    struct GEAR_EXPORT MODULE : public ParameterType
    {
        /* MODULE parameter's unit type definition */
        using UnitType = si::length;
        /* MODULE parameter's data type definition */
        using DataType = double;
        /* MODULE parameter's DesignRules DB ID */
        using ID = std::integral_constant<ParameterType::IDType, 2>;
    };

    /* ... many others similarly defined as above follows */
};
```

I know the tags should be left empty classes so that compiler can optimize them away but the advantage of having the type definitions inside exceeds the compiler optimization benefit. **I hope this is not the cause of my troubles as described below?**

Then I have a ParameterContainer class which supplies a set of templated methods like this one:

```
template<typename PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>
bool isSet( void ) const
{
    /* Once the find() reaches the end of the container, the parameter is not in */
    if( mStorage.find( PARAM_IDENTIFICATION::ID::value ) == mStorage.end() )
        return( false );
    else
        return( true );
}
```

It accepts single template parameter PARAM_IDENTIFICATION which acts as the Tag (Tag dispatching by type). The method is used as follows ***[WORKS]***:

```
if( TestContainer.isSet<GearParams::NUM_OF_TEETH>() == true )
{
    /* do something */
}
```

This is working fine. But once I try to use it in templated method like this ***[FAILS]***:

```
template<typename PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>
bool check( void ) const
{
    return( mParameters.isSet<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>() );
}
```

But even the compilation fails bacause of:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
    return( mParameters.isSet<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>() );
                                                  ^
```

and

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
    return( mParameters.isSet<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>() );
                                                    ^
```

I know the primary expression error is usually cause by type/instance mixup.
What I do not understand is that when I use the `isSet()` method with a complete type `GearParams::NUM_OF_TEETH` it works but fails when using the same via templated method:

```
check<GearParams::NUM_OF_TEETH>();
```

What is the difference? What's wrong with my code? I would expect the same implementation would behave somehow consistently... am I missing something in my code?

Many thanks in advance to anybody willing to help...

Comment: try `mParameters.template isSet<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mParameters.template isSet<PARAM_IDENTIFICATION>()`.

According to the latest standard draft, $14.2.4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a postfix-expression or after a
>   nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object expression of the postfix-expression is type-dependent
>   or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Comment: Many thanks Vittorio. You advice solved the errors reported.